# Get value extracted based on 2 criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider I have 2 tables which are in same sheet.

Table 1: Sales and Table 2: Production

In Sales table I need to calculate the profit column. Its data will be picked from Production cost table based on the Type and Size from Sales table.

Suppose I have sold 5000 ml 1 qty Groundnut so first it should search for the production cost for 5000ml ground nut in production table.
In the current example if I sold 5000ml qty of groundnut then it manufacturing cost should pe extract in the column so that I can subtract it from my sales price.

**Production Cost Table :**

[image: production]

**Sales Table :**

[image]

Comment: use a horizontal `match` with match_type=1 on quantity  to get which production column you need (100/200/500). Use a vertical `match` to get which product type row you need. Use those two in an `offset` to get the appropriate cell returned.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis : thanks for your Reply but can u give me some reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `INDEX/MATCH` function.

```
=INDEX($B$3:$D$7,MATCH(F3,$A$3:$A$7,0),MATCH(G3,$B$2:$D$2,0))
```

[image]